# ASPNetZero solution structure to meet the following goals

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm migrating an old SAAS solution to ASPNETZERO, we are tackling the following issue, to make it easy to update the solution regularly when aspnetzero releases update we are thinking of adding to the current solution are own set of the c# library project, in which we are defining our own Application, Application.Shared, Core, Core.Shared and EntityFrameworkCore.
The idea is to try to keep the original solution untouched in it's core as we possibly can but i have doubts. Can you please share with me your thoughts on this matter and give me some insights.

Answer (score 0):

The changes are codebehind and client side changes. Even you succeed in protecting the code base for codebehind it is hard to update client code. What I recommend; periodically  fork the Aspnet Zero from GitHub and merge changes. 
Anyway if somebody has come with a brilliant idea I would like to learn.